# use foreach in differents cases

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

this is "query" object

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Name of the user",
    query: "The query of the user",
}
```

this is "user" object

```
{
    name:'Name of User'
}
```

there are many users so i made an array that contains all the users
and an array that contains all the queries

```
query_array=ko.observableArray([{//query},{//other query}])
user_array=ko.observableArray([{//user},{//other user}])
```

this is my view model

```
var viewModel=function()
{
    var self=this;
    self.users=user_array;
    self.queries=query_array;
}
```

my jade template index.jade

```
div.span12(data-bind='foreach:user')
    legend(data-bind="text:name")
```

this works fine... but i need this

```
div.span12(data-bind='foreach:users')
    legend(data-bind="text:name")
    div.span12(data-bind="foreach:queries")
        //if query name == user.name
        span(data-bind="text:query")
        br
```

how can i do this in knockout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Paul's got it.  But since I spent time on this fiddle, here's an [alternate solution](http://jsfiddle.net/LeCodeNinja/W8vQT/) that uses nested bindings.  The trick is in how the bindings are called.  $data.name is the current user's name, while $root reaches out the the view model root.

```
<!-- ko foreach: $root.users -->
<p>
    <div data-bind="text:$data.name"></div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: $root.queries">
        <li data-bind="visible: $data.name == $parent.name">
            <div data-bind="text: $data.query"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: it works really great, i think this is what im looking for, but i have a little problem, even with Paul's solution. When i push an other element to the user array or to the query array, there no refreshing the view, but the arrays have the new element.

Comment: This updated fiddle adds a button for faking interactivity and it seems to work:  http://jsfiddle.net/LeCodeNinja/W8vQT/1/  I'd check to make sure that you're not wiping out the observable array with a regular array.  Maybe try adding the "pre debugger"?

Comment: my mistake... im pushing the elements like viewModel.queries().push() instead of queries.push()

Answer (score 0):

I would pre-process your query array, and add an array to the user object containing the queries for that user. Something like this:

```
var viewModel=function()
{
    var self=this;
    self.users=user_array;
    self.queries=query_array;

    for(var i = 0; i < self.users().length; i++)
    {
        var user = users()[i];
        var username = user.name.toLowerCase();
        user.queries = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.queries(), function(query)
        {
            return query.name.toLowerCase() === username;
        }));
    }
}
```

Your Jade template should work without any modifications needed.